# How to reword this without using additional nouns?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This sentence doesn't feel correct.

> There were a lot of photos that I didn't know who they were.

But I'm not sure how to reword it without changing its structure. I could use additional nouns, like

> There were a lot of photos whose identity I didn't know.

But ideally, I wanted to keep the sentence order similar and avoid additional words.

Comment: What meaning are you trying to convey?

Comment: @Lordology that there are a bunch of photos of people, and I don't know the people in them.

Comment: Please add this information to your question.  Thanks!

Comment: I've downvoted the question because of its stated desire to avoid "additional" words.  They're not additional at all, but necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point, you're going to have to add 'of people', otherwise it seems like you don't recognise the photos themselves, because you're talking about the people *who are in the photos.*

Adding 'of people' to either of your examples would not help as both of them are unidiomatic as it is.

I think the best you're going to get is:

> There were a lot of photos **of people** I didn't know.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

"There were a lot of photos of people I didn't know."

Comment: Hi Jordan, welcome to EL&U! Your answer would be better suited as a comment, so I have flagged it as 'not an answer'. If you would like to post an answer, please consider **editing** and **improving** your post. It would also be worth checking out how to answer well in the help center.